# Конфликт имён в c++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

int i = 1;

int main()
{
        int i = 112;
        std::cout<<i<<std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Выводит на экран 112.
Вопрос:Почему нету конфликта имён?

Comment: а почему собственно должен быть?

Comment: @SergeyTatarincev ну ведь две переменной с одинаковым именем

Comment: одна внутри функции, вторая глобальная. Все верно, согласно синтаксису

Comment: Разные области видимости, никакого конфликта не будет. Просто та, что внутри функции перекроет ту, что снаружи.

Answer (score 4):

Потому что имя внутри блока скрывает имя снаружи.

Но это не беда - к нему все равно можно обратиться, указав глобальную область видимости:

```
    std::cout<<i<<std::endl;    // Локальная переменная

    std::cout<<::i<<std::endl;  // Глобальная переменная
```